# Steps to setup angular app in Google Cloud App Engine and Go Daddy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns, godaddy-api

I want to deploy an angular app is n Google Cloud Platform App Engine, and link to my domain in Go Daddy.

I have done the domain verification in Google, and able to do npm start in cloud shell and web preview it, however need help with below: 
1. How to persist the deployment even if I close the shell? Adding & to make it a background process enough?
2. What should be the values in Go Daddy DNS configurations 
3. If I deploy on another port, such as 4200, how to forward http, https, and www to that port?

Any help us much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: 3. You need to forward ports https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding
2. Do you have the DNS record displayed after a domain verification?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I can see that in google. But what are the values I need to provide in Godaddy for www and @ fields?

Comment: For the values that you need to provide, I found a combination of [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l--TJabo2M) quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `npm start` in the Cloud Shell to web preview it you’re only running the app “locally” in Cloud Shell, you’re not actually deploying it to App Engine. To deploy your app you should use the `gcloud app deploy` command.

The general steps on how to deploy the app in App Engine  are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_application)

Regarding the DNS values to map your custom domain please follow the steps 4, 5 and 6 in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application)

In order to understand how Port forwarding works in App Engine I recommend checking this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#port_forwarding).

If you are interested there's also a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) where you can go through all the steps on deploying an Angular app to App Engine.